# Ubuntu Coovachilli freeradius phpmyprepaid

Tags: server, php

I have installed `Freeradius Coovachilli Captive portal` successfully on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. but when i downloaded `Phpmyprepaid RC3` and extracted to `/var/www/html` folder it returns a login page and cant login, and few php errors.. its supposed to come a setup page.

What Goes Wrong .. Attached Screen Capture

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

find for: `short_open_tag=Off`

and set it to: `short_open_tag=On`

Comment: And why, please explain?